# Diffeomorphism and Orientable double cover

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that the orientable double cover of two homeomorphic surfaces are diffeomorphic, is it true that these surfaces are diffeomorphic?

Comment: And by surfaces, do you mean $2$-dimensional smooth manifolds?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval yes.

Comment: I think that in the $2$-dimensional case every two homeomorphic manifolds are necessarily diffeomorphic.